# Вывод постов с сообщества вк

Tags: jquery, vkontakte-api

Хочу вывести посты со стены сообщества

```
    function gotData( data){
    var i, post, html="";
    if( !data  ||  !data.response  ||  !data.response.items) {
        console.error( "VK returned some crap:", data);
        return;
    }
    for( i=0; i<data.response.items.length; i++) {
        post = data.response.items[i];
        //html += '<div class="post well">'+post.id+'</div>';
        tml = "<div id='vk_post_-10639516_"+post.id+"'></div><script type='text/javascript'>  (function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = '//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?121'; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'vk_openapi_js'));  (function() {    if (!window.VK || !VK.Widgets || !VK.Widgets.Post || !VK.Widgets.Post('vk_post_-10639516_"+post.id+"', -10639516, "+post.id+", 'bI6jkO3CTgT_zS04pq7BOw1xX3hL', {width: 500})) setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);  }());<\/script>";
    }
    $('#v').html(tml);
}


$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get",
    data: {
        domain: "mdk",
        count: 5,
        filter: "owner",
        v: "5.26",
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",    
    success: gotData,
});
```

Просто id хорошо выводятся все работает,и отдельно один пост выводится,но при выводе нескольких пишет ошибка доступа. Это же открытый метод не нужен токен,подкажите как быть?

Comment: Так он все вам и возвращает. Ошибка доступа у вас там, где в ответе в переменной `tml` еще и скрипт  пишется с параметрами... вот там и ошибка как раз

Comment: Получается,так нельзя только один параметр динамичным сделать,нужно все изменять в `tml` ? Или как быть?

Comment: Не по теме: вы пишете комменты на английском? Мне показался знакомым текст в 4-й строке )

Comment: @zkolya дело в том, что у каждого виджета свой хэш. Не знаю как он вычисляется. Но использовать один хэш на все виджеты не получится.. Можете попытаться узнать у разрабов как он вычисляется и можно ли так делать) ..... а почему вам надо это всё выводить виджетами? а не самому нарисовать `html` на основе полученных данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы выводить посты со стены сообщества у себя на сайте лучше воспользоваться [виджетом «Сообщества»](https://vk.com/dev/Community?height=400&link=http%3A%2F%2Fvk.com%2Fmdk&mode=2&oid=-10639516&wide=&width=500), в режиме «Новости»:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?121"></script>

<!-- VK Widget -->
<div id="vk_groups"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 2, width: "640", height: "480"}, 10639516);
</script>
```

С помощью JS / jQuery вы можете получать содержание постов, но придётся самостоятельно генерировать всю разметку. Ответ api содержит как текст, так и параметры приложений к посту (картинок, видео) – вам лишь нужно правильно их показать.

Генерировать [виджет «Запись на стене»](https://vk.com/dev/Post) автоматически – не получится из-за параметра `hash`, как правильно заметил @Алексей-Шиманский.

```js
function gotData( data){
    var i, post, result='', html;
    if( !data  ||  !data.response  ||  !data.response.items) {
        console.error( "VK returned some crap:", data);
        return;
    }
    for( i=0; i<data.response.items.length; i++) {
        post = data.response.items[i];
        if( post.text.length) {
          html = post.text;
        } else {
          // пост без текста – только приложение (картинка, видео, ссылка и т.п.)
          html = "attachment: " + post.attachments[0].type;
        }
        result += '<div class="post well">'+html+'</div>';
    }
    $('#posts').html(result);
}


$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get",
    data: {
        domain: "mdk",
        count: 5,
        filter: "owner",
        v: "5.26",
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",    
    success: gotData,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="posts" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: А как более экономичнее, виджет или самому разметку повторить?

Comment: Зависит от ваших задач. Меньше работы – виджет: поставил, и работает : )