# Как можно сделать чтобы на сайте появлялись актуальные новости с группы вк?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Гуглил, ничего не нашел.
Я могу использовать любые web языки, в том числе и php (но легче на html).

Есть такой сайт, называется биг хост. Увидел на их сайте такую штуку, а именно всегда актуальные новости вк (то есть они выложили - и сразу это появляется на сайте)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать такую же штуку? Спасибо заранее за ответ.

Comment: Документацию пытались читать? https://dev.vk.com/widgets/community-messages

Comment: А если точнее, то вам вот это нужно: [Виджет для сообщества](https://dev.vk.com/widgets/group#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0). И да, плохо [гуглили](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4+%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B+%D0%92%D0%9A+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

Comment: а когда кастом понадобится - то вэбхуки

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод постов с сообщества вк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483070/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%ba)